# Is one allowed to cancel a check?

Tags: money, choshen-mishpat-civil-law, transactions, legal-documents, halacha

If I give a check to someone (as a gift) and I change my mind, am I halachically allowed to cancel it, or do we say that the check is a shtar, and by signing it is considered as if I gave him the money?

Comment: Why should you be allowed?

Comment: If it is not a shtar, just a piece of paper informing the bank to give this person money, then why shouldn't I be able to cancel it?

Answer (score 2):

Based on the [legal definition](http://www.duhaime.org/LegalDictionary/C/CheckorCheque.aspx) of a check it would seem to me that it is alot more than just a piece of paper, and you have no right to cancel it.

Comment: According to the definition you linked to, you should be able to cancel.  Although it is more than a piece of paper, it doesn't seem to create an hischayavus, just the right to draw from your account.

Comment: I will let the scholars determine if my interpertation or yours is correct.

Answer (score 2):

I would argue that part of the institution of check-writing is the understanding that one may cancel the transfer of funds at any time up until the funds have actually been drawn.  Keep in mind:

1. If a dispute arises over the legitimacy of the check itself, or if one decides to cancel a gift, then one has that right.  I think that in many cases, like this one, Halachah would follow the normative practice with regard to the vehicle used to transfer the funds.
2. The check is NOT a contract.  I cannot execute a purchase of real property by writing "Property purchase - 123 Main St., Anytown, IL 12345" in the memo line of a check without a separate, fully binding contract dealing with said purchase.  A mere phone call to the bank would override whatever is written on the check.

Comment: Re "The check is NOT a contract. I cannot execute a purchase... by writing... in the memo line...": True, but it is a legally effective document authorizing the drawee to do something. And (CYLattorney, but I think) statements the drawer puts atop the endorsement area which are signed under are binding. (I wonder whether "I hereby give drawer 123 Main St., Anytown, IL 12345; these funds are consideration." there works.)

Comment: But the underlying principle is that the writer of the check retains the right to cancel it until the funds have been drawn. A mere phone call to the bank would override whatever is written on the check, hence it is not a binding contract.

Comment: True, and that's what you said in the first paragraph of the answer. I wasn't sure where you were going with your "The check is NOT a contract..." point, so simply addressed it at its face value in my previous comment.

Comment: @msh210 Do my edits make my point clearer?

Comment: Yes, very nicely.